# C program debugging in gdb problem

Tags: gdb

I'm trying to run my app on gdb. Therefore I compiled it with the 'g' option. But when I'm running `gdb ./app` I get:

```
DW_FORM_strp pointing outside of .debug_str section [in module /home/w/app]
```

And I cannot do any break:

```
(gdb) break main
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command. 
(gdb) .
```

Comment: What OS and CPU ? Have you tried running gdb with a simple "Hello World" test app to make sure your basic gcc/gdb tool chain is installed and working OK ?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you've compiled your program with a newer version of GCC, but are debugging it with an old GDB.

Else, you have a buggy GCC version, which puts incorrect debug info into your executable.

Answer (score 1):

Use `objdump -W` to look at the Elf file's Dwarf debug information to see the `.debug_str` table.

Each `DW_FORM_strp` is an offset into this table.

Compiling with `-g` (or `-g-dwarf2`) puts the Dwarf information in each object file
with its own portion of `.debug_str` section strings.

Linking those object files with -g tries to make unique strings and doesn't update all the `DW_FORM_strp` offsets properly. Seen with gcc 4.3.4's ld.

We were pasing `CC_FLAGS` to a makefile link step by accident.

Workaround : don't link with `-g` flag.